# Does Flames of Phlegethos let a character reroll a 1 on the damage from Flame Arrows if fired by another creature besides the caster with the feat?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, feats

The [*flame arrows*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/flame-arrows) spell enchants a quiver so that every arrow/bolt fired from that quiver deals an extra 1d6 fire damage. I assumed that any creature (including the caster's allies) can draw and fire these arrows.

The caster has the [Flames of Phlegethos](https://www.dndbeyond.com/characters/feats/flames-of-phlegethos) tiefling racial feat (*Xanathar's Guide to Everything*, p. 74-75), which has the following benefit, among others:

> When you roll fire damage for a spell you cast, you can reroll any roll of 1 on the fire damage dice, but you must use the new roll, even if it is another 1.

It is obvious that if the caster attacks using the flame arrow (an arrow from the enchanted quiver), Flames of Phlegethos would work for them because they are the one cast the spell. However, how about the other creature firing the flame arrow? **If they are not the one who cast the spell, can they reroll the extra fire damage on a 1?**

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## Yes, a 1 on the damage could be rerolled

Reading the rule literally, the feat only applies if the spellcaster is the one physically rolling the damage dice. So the question is whether or not the caster can roll the dice for their *Flame Arrows* spell.

The spell text says:

> When a target is hit by a ranged weapon attack using a piece of ammunition drawn from the quiver, **the target takes** an extra 1d6 fire damage.

*Fireball*, which I think most tables would agree is unambiguously covered by Flames of Phlegethos, uses similar wording.

> A bright streak flashes from your pointing finger to a point you choose within range and then blossoms with a low roar into an explosion of flame. Each creature in a 20-foot-radius sphere centered on that point must make a Dexterity saving throw. **A target takes** 8d6 fire damage on a failed save, or half as much damage on a successful one.

It seems reasonable to me to read that the Flame Arrows spell is applying the damage, and the caster of the spell is entitled to roll the d6 (and reroll as appropriate) regardless of who is firing the bow.

At my table, I would probably let the archer roll the fire damage for expediency, but the rerolls would still apply.

Comment: I was originally thinking no, but good job on finding matching wording that suggests the damage can be rolled by the caster even when fired by a different player.

Answer (score -4):

"When you roll fire damage for a spell you cast"

If you didn't cast the spell, the 1 does NOT get rerolled.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance. This doesn't answer the question, which assumes that *flame arrows* is cast by the tiefling with the feat - it's just being cast on someone else's quiver.

Comment: Please note that as written, this does not answer the querent's question. The original question was asking whether extra damage rolls for fire effects due to a long-term spell that the caster did cast are affected by the Flames of Phlegothos feature.